Python. exe causing ' WinError 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' when removing .mp4 local temp file
I'm running a very simple code snippet in my flask app that downloads a local tmp .mp4 file as the output.
The output file is then uploaded to the cloud and ideally, the local tmp file removed to free server space.


import os
import gc
import sieve

def run_autocrop(video_path, s3_client):

    file = sieve.File(path = video_path)
    active_speaker_detection = True
    aspect_ratio = "9:16"
    return_video = True
    start_time = 0
    end_time = -1
    speed_boost = True
    smart_edit = False
    visualize = False
    include_subjects = False
    include_non_active_layouts = False
    prompt = "person"
    negative_prompt = ""
    single_crop_only = False
    crop_movement_speed = 0.0
    crop_sampling_interval = 7


    autocrop = sieve.function.get("sieve/autocrop")
    output = autocrop.run(file, active_speaker_detection, aspect_ratio, return_video, start_time, end_time, speed_boost, smart_edit, visualize, include_subjects, include_non_active_layouts, prompt, negative_prompt, single_crop_only, crop_movement_speed, crop_sampling_interval)

    #release resources
    del file
    gc.collect()

    #get output file path
    for output_object in output:
        temp_path = output_object.path

    # upload the file to Wasabi
    s3_client.upload_file(temp_path, 'my-cloud-bucket', 'cloud-path-and-filename')

    # delete the local file
    if os.path.exists(temp_path):
        os.remove(temp_path)

    return print('Done!')



The script executes normally until it's time to remove the local file, then I get this error:
ERROR:root:Error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptjengzrw.mp4'

Turns out that the actual process using the file is Python.exe. I can't kill Python, so I can't force-close the process using it, and at the same time the code is so "simple" that I can't point out where and how Python would have the file still open. There are other modules in my code where I'm creating and removing video files without a problem, it's just this specific file created by the autocrop function. Even if I try to manually deleting it via the file explorer I get a pop-up indicating it is being used by Python. exe and it's not until I terminate my flask app (Ctr+C) that I'm able to delete the file.
How can I make sure the file is closed, so I can delete it in the same script after uploading to the cloud?
Thanks!

Are you sure the autocrop.run() function closes the file handler? The upload_file is a blocking function and closes the file when done with execution, so that should not be the problem.
